# how to set a var outside of an async function to use in $scope object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, nvd3.js

For the last two days I've been reading about promises, callbacks, and generators trying to figure out how I can set a value from a async function that I can then use in a $scope object.

I can't get the promise to resolve then to the `var`, it just returns the promise and not the value, which is what its supposed to do from what I understand. This is where I thought maybe a generator would help maybe?

So, how do I set a `var` from an async function so that I can use that `var` in the object `$scope.options_scn_cst`

This is specifically for nvd3, as what I'm trying to do, is to loop through the results from the loopback function `Rpt_scn_cost_v` to find the max value, and then set that as the max value in the Y axis in `yDomain: [min, max]` for nvd3.

My code right now looks like this:

```
function maxYvalue2() {
    return Rpt_scn_cost_v.find({filter: { where: {scenario_id: $stateParams.id}}}).$promise.then(function(response){
        var maxYvalue = 0;
        var currMaxYvalue = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
            var currMaxYvalue = parseFloat(response[i].cur_cost) + parseFloat(response[i].tgt_cost);
            if (currMaxYvalue > maxYvalue) {
                maxYvalue = currMaxYvalue;
            };
        }
        return maxYvalue;
        console.log("yVal: ", maxYvalue)
    });
};

var mxY = 100000 // <======== when I set it to this maxYvalue2(), it resolves in a promise

console.log('var', mxY)




$scope.options_scn_cst = {
        chart: {
            type: 'lineChart',
            height: 450,
            margin : {
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 40,
                left: 55
            },
            x: function(d){ return d.x; },
            y: function(d){ return d.y; },
            useInteractiveGuideline: true,
            dispatch: {
                stateChange: function(e){ console.log("stateChange"); },
                changeState: function(e){ console.log("changeState"); },
                tooltipShow: function(e){ console.log("tooltipShow"); },
                tooltipHide: function(e){ console.log("tooltipHide"); }
            },
            xAxis: {
                axisLabel: '',
                tickFormat: function(d) { return d3.time.format('%b %y')(new Date(d)); }
            },
            yDomain: [0, mxY], // <============ I then set mxY here in the $scope object
            yAxis: {
                axisLabel: '$ / month',
                tickFormat: function(d){
                    return d3.format('$,.0f')(d);
                },
                axisLabelDistance: -10
            },
            callback: function(chart){}
        },
        title: {
            enable: true,
            text: 'Scenario Costs Over Time'
        },
        subtitle: {
            enable: false,
            text: 'Put your Subtitle here.',
            css: {
                'text-align': 'center',
                'margin': '10px 13px 0px 7px'
            }
        },
        caption: {
            enable: false,
            html: 'Put your Caption Here.',
            css: {
                'text-align': 'justify',
                'margin': '10px 13px 0px 7px'
            }
        }
    };
```

and then I call the $scope object like this then:

```
<nvd3 data="data_scn_cst" options="options_scn_cst"></nvd3>
```

I tried this way as well using $q, but it returns the promise and not the value too...

```
function maxYvalue2() {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

     Rpt_scn_cost_v.find({filter: { where: {scenario_id: $stateParams.id}}}).$promise.then(function(response){
        var maxYvalue = 0;
        var currMaxYvalue = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
            var currMaxYvalue = parseFloat(response[i].cur_cost) + parseFloat(response[i].tgt_cost);
            if (currMaxYvalue > maxYvalue) {
                maxYvalue = currMaxYvalue;
            };
        }
         deferred.resolve(maxYvalue)
        console.log("yVal: ", maxYvalue)
    });

    return deferred.promise
};

var mxY = maxYvalue2() // <======== when I set it to this maxYvalue2(), it resolves in a promise

console.log('var', mxY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your code is by nature asynchronous, you will never get it into your var synchronously, whichever methods you try.

You have a few ways to work around that. One option is to wait until the promise resolves (using its `then` method) and then, and only then, create your `$scope.options_scn_cst` object.

```
maxYvalue2().then(function(maxYvalue) {
    // Now that we know maxYvalue, define the scope variable
    $scope.options_scn_cst = {...}
})
```

This of course requires that the `<nvd3>` directive that you use watches over its `options` binding to detect that the variable is there once it is defined.

If it is no the case and the `nvd3` is your directive, you can use `$scope.$watch('options', function() {...})`

If it is not the case and the `nvd3` directive is not yours, you could surround it in some `ng-if` element to only display it once options_scn_cst exists:

```
<nvd3 ng-if="options_scn_cst" data="data_scn_cst" options="options_scn_cst"></nvd3>
```

Comment: here's a question too...how would I use generators instead or promises?

Answer (score 2):

`Rpt_scn_cost_v.find` returns a promise, I assume. This lets you chain the promise and use the result:

```
function maxYvalue2() {
    return Rpt_scn_cost_v.find({filter: { where: {scenario_id: $stateParams.id}}}).then(function(response){
        var maxYvalue = 0;
        var currMaxYvalue = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<response.length;i++) {
            var currMaxYvalue = parseFloat(response[i].cur_cost) + parseFloat(response[i].tgt_cost);
            if (currMaxYvalue > maxYvalue) {
                maxYvalue = currMaxYvalue;
            }
        }
        return maxYvalue;
    });
}
```

Use by:

```
maxYvalue2().then(function(maxYvalue) {
    console.log('maxYvalue=', maxYvalue);
});
```